# Custom Control OnPaint does not fire

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, onpaint

I have the following custom `Control`:

```
public class Line : Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
        {
            var point1 = new Point(234, 118);
            var point2 = new Point(293, 228);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, point1, point2);
        }
    }
}
```

And a `Form` where I add as new control a new instance of the `Line` class:

```
Controls.Add(new Line());
```

The problem is that the method OnPaint isn't called and no line is drawn. Why? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are not giving it a Size, try creating a Constructor and setting a default size there, you also seem to be using the parent controls coordinates, I would use the location of the Usercontrol to set your start position and only be concerned with the Width and Height of the control needed to contain your line.

```
public  Line()
{
     Size = new Size(500, 500);
}
```

Comment: Well it works, but I have a strange problem... I can draw a single line: if I add another control it isn't draw... I just added another `Controls.Add(new Line());` instruction (following the first). Do you know why?

Comment: probably being placed at the same location, What you are doing is creating a control that has a square region and depending on the coordinates of your second control it is probably be covered up.

Comment: Ok, but suppose I have to draw two lines in order to display the character `X`, both my controls have the same `Size` (for example 50x50) and the same position (only the two lines have different coordinates). How can I display the second line without cover the other?

Comment: That is one of the downfalls of using winforms, you do not have true transparency. You would be better off drawing your x on the same control, doing your drawing on the container or installing the [visual basic powerpack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169) and using the LineShape